# Lightweight Groovy and JSF (JSF2/Primefaces) integration

Tags: jsf, groovy, primefaces, eclipselink

I'm researching lightweight Groovy and JSF integrations, but I'v found only in Grails style.

My requirement is different, core of application in TomEE / JEE / JSF style, but in few screens want to present (kind of) "Groovy Entities" in JSF database components.

I use "Groovy Entity" or "Groovy Bean" definition: GroovyObject with properties dynamically added in Groovy style (incompatible with classic Java)

My project is kind of Intranet, with universal "core" code and "extensions" for customers. It is not Grails application. 
Currently based on Eclipselink JPA, maybe with "dynamic entities" in Eclipselink sense.

This is not "opinion based question", I can make my tests & opinion, even extend code, want only short direction.

Comment: if it is not opinion based, it is _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "_

Comment: "I have find Grails type solutions" ??? And I give criteria